# How to update on object at a certain position in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, javabeans

I have one ArrayList of 10 Objects.

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(new Person("Jean", "Pol", "receptionist", 29));
persons.add(new Person("Jef", "Snijders", "guardener", 42));
persons.add(new Person("Piet", "Peters", "truck driver", 54));
persons.add(new Person("Peet", "Polders", "professor", 63));
persons.add(new Person("Nell", "Van Den Walle", "student", 19));
persons.add(new Person("Nady", "Van Toren", "cleaning", 27));
persons.add(new Person("Jenny", "De Koster", "police", 39));
persons.add(new Person("Malena", "Zetterman", "air traffic controler", 45));
persons.add(new Person("Medina", "Zegers", "test engineer", 25));
persons.add(new Person("Horaire", "Safrina", "manager", 39));
```

Another method in the applications creates an changed object:

```
Person changed = new Person("Jean", "Pol", "officer", 30);
```

How do I find this object in the list, and update the list?
(this should actually update the first object in the list)

This is the Person bean:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String jobTitle;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String jobTitle, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.age = age;
    }


    // Getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Comment: do you need the order?

Comment: Your `Person` class should have a `pid` to identify. Else you can use one of the answers below to solve the problem.

Comment: You can't find that object in the list, because that object isn't in the list.

Comment: Any modification to the code is good. The idea of an index is very good as long as we can find it easily afterwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing an element in the List can be done by :

```
persons.set(0,changed);
```

However, finding the index of the element to change requires iterating over the entire List. You should consider using a HashMap instead (where the key identifies the Person).

Then

```
persons.put (personID, changed);
```

will replace the Person whose ID is `personID` (you'll need to have some unique property in the Person class, and override `hashCode` and `equals` in order to make that work).

Answer (score 2):

You should tell java about "On what basis should i consider two person equals"? For that you have to override `equals()` method and do an equality check based on `firstName` and `lastName`. However since it is a list, so you will have to iterate over it and use `contains(Person p)` method to check if it exists (Which will use `equals` method). Once you find a matching `Person` object, you can replace it (using the index).

Answer (score 1):

first decide which property or properties can be used to verify if 2 objects are equal then override equals and hashcode for persons and then iterate and compare then replace when found.

Answer (score 1):

the best approach to find the object is to override two methods `equals(Object o)` and `hashCode()` within your `Person` class, this will define a unique Person

your Person class:

```
class Person {
...

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
// your code here
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
//your code here
}

}
```

if ordering is not important to you , you can use `HashMap`

for example :

```
Person p;//
myMap.put(p.hashCode(),p);
```

then from other part of your application you get your person;

```
Person otherP;//
myMap.put(otherP.hashCode(), otherP) // this will replaces the previous person with the same hashCode with the modified code
```

if you don't want to add a person that is not already there, you can check if it exists first

```
if(myMap.containsKey(otherP.hashCode()){
    myMap.put(otherP.hashCode(), otherP);//
}
```

Answer (score 1):

generate hashcode and equals methods in your bean class for the variable you want to check for similarity (in your case the firstName property in person class).if using eclipse then pressing ctrl+shift+s shows you the option to generate hashcode and equals methods.
what this does is to override the default equals method. Please make sure that you are selecting only the properties which you know will be same.

```
if (List.contains(new_object)) { // checking if object is in the list
    int indexPos = List.indexOf(new_object); // getting the index if there
    dbStockObjList.set(indexPos, new_object);//adding it in the index
}
```

the hashcode and equals methods for your bean would look like this:

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

hope this answers your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [List#indexOf(obj)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method to get the index of the "identical" object, and update it using [List#set(index, object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)).

Note that it will require you to override `equals()` method for your object.

Also note: this operation is inefficient, and if the list is large and the number of changes is frequent - consider switching from a list to a "smarter" data type, such as a `Set`.